# Doctrine returning blank for new field added to database

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have recently added a new field to my database and have added some new getters and setters to my Doctrine model like so:

```
/**
* @Column(type="text", length=65000, nullable=true)
*/
private $iframeCode;

...

public function getIframeCode(){
  return $this->iframeCode;
}

...

public function setIframeCode($val){
    $this->iframeCode = $val;
}
```

This works well locally, and everything is fine. As soon as I upload to the server though, empty strings are always returned whenever I call `getIframeCode()` on an object, even when I have manually entered values for the field into the database. There are no errors, just empty values returned.

I thought it must be caching (I'm using APC), but I tried using `apc_clear_cache()` without any luck. Is there something that I'm overlooking?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have figured out that it IS in fact the caching thats causing this. My question now would be, whats the best and safest way of clearing the cache when you're making a change like this on a production server?

Comment: I'd use [Doctrine's cache clearing commands](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#command-overview) instead of diving straight into `apc_clear_cache()`

Comment: So on our staging environment I changed it to array caching and the problem was fixed. Is there a "production safe" way of clearing the Doctrine cache when a change like this is required?

Comment: I usually just make clearing the caches part of the deployment process. The CLI console / scripts are definitely production safe, just keep them outside the document root